# Leetcode Combination Sum IV: Java solution works but C++ throws integer overflow error

Tags: java, c++

I was trying to solve this question.

https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/

Consider the following test case

```
[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,290,300,310,320,330,340,350,360,370,380,390,400,410,420,430,440,450,460,470,480,490,500,510,520,530,540,550,560,570,580,590,600,610,620,630,640,650,660,670,680,690,700,710,720,730,740,750,760,770,780,790,800,810,820,830,840,850,860,870,880,890,900,910,920,930,940,950,960,970,980,990,111]
999
```

The following Java solution works well on this test case

```
class Solution {
    public int combinationSum4(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] comb = new int[target + 1];
        comb[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < comb.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (i - nums[j] >= 0) {
                    comb[i] += comb[i - nums[j]];
                }
            }
        }
        return comb[target];
    }
}
```

However the following C++ code which is equivalent (or should I say nearly identical) to the above Java code throws signed integer overflow.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int combinationSum4(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> comb(target + 1, 0);
        comb[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < comb.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {
                if (i - nums[j] >= 0) {
                    comb[i] += comb[i - nums[j]];
                }
            }
        }
        return comb[target];
    }
};
```

The following is the error I get with the above C++ code.

```
Line 9: Char 29: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:18:29
```

**Could you please provide an explanation to this discrepancy between the two nearly identical solutions in Java and C++?**

Also please note that I get this signed integer overflow error even when I use `long long int` in the C++ code.

Comment: It's likely that both of your examples overflow, but only the c++ example warns about it, as signed integer overflow is UB in C++.

Comment: *Could you please provide an explanation to this discrepancy* -- You should use the debugger to figure this out.  You have the code, the test case, etc., thus no reason to not be able to debug the code.  -- *between the two nearly identical solutions in Java and C++?* -- C++ is not Java, Java is not C++.  The two solutions are not "identical", since you are using different computer languages, with different syntax, with different rules.

Comment: According to the problem description, `target` is guaranteed to be a value in the range [1,1000] so I'm curious to know how you got the runtime error about `2147483647 + 1`. Presumably that's coming from `target + 1`, which means `target` is out of range according to the specified constraints.

Comment: If you had created a [mcve], similar to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GxzP33fd1), you would have discovered that given the data, and running through the known targets, you will see the ones that give negative results.  Then take one of those targets and debug your code to see why it goes negative (more than likely due to signed int overflow).

Comment: Note that `undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:18:29` gives you the exact line and column of where the error occurs. Should help finding the offending  code...

Comment: Also, `2147483647` is surprisingly similar to `INT_MAX`, and would be a good corner case test for `target`.